# TclError unknown option when unpacking a dictionary into treeview.insert (tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter, tcl

I have treeview tree built like so:

```
tree = ttk.Treeview(self.treeview_frame, columns=columns,
                                 yscrollcommand=scroll_y.set,
                                 xscrollcommand=scroll_x.set,
                                 show="headings")

for name in columns:
    tree.column(name, anchor=tk.W, width=150, stretch=True)
    tree.heading(name, text=name, anchor=tk.CENTER)
```

Where `columns` for this example would be ["Annotation Name"].

I have a dictionary `input_dict`:

```
{'parent': '',
 'iid': 'Shell-local',
 'text': 'Shell-local (Ann.)',
 'image': None,
 'values': ('Shell Annotation',),
 'open': True,
 'tags': [],
 'index': 'end'}
```

Which matches the required keyword arguments for [treeview.insert()](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/tkinter.ttk.html#item-options),
but when executing the following:
`self.tree.insert(**input_dict)`

The below error occurs:

```
File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\aat\lib\tkinter\ttk.py", line 1361, in insert
    res = self.tk.call(self._w, "insert", parent, index,
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "{Shell Annotation}"
```

I've tries replacing the backspace character with '\b':

```
new_values = tuple([str(val).replace(" ", "\b") for val in input_dict["values"]])
input_dict["values"] = new_values
```

But...:

```
File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\aat\lib\tkinter\ttk.py", line 1361, in insert
    res = self.tk.call(self._w, "insert", parent, index,
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "ShelAnnotation"
```

The reason I don't just assign the input arguments like this `self.tree.insert(index=input_dict["index"],...)` is because the `input_dict` is the result of `__dict__` of a dataclass, and I want the code to be flexible with changes in the dataclass.

Anyone knows what causes these errors?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `'image' = None` is responsible.
After popping the key 'image' from `input_dict` the code works.